# Positioning Extruders after Tool change : Marlin 1.1.6

Tags: marlin, dual-nozzle

I'm currently working on a project which uses two extruders. One for making an impression in a powder and other one to dispose a liquid in to the impression made by the first extruder.

I'm currently manually writing gcode for the purpose, and have some doubts about gcodes and setting up a second extruder. I've once configured a dual extruder system, but it uses old marlin and current one has a variety of dual extruder system, so confused about which one to choose.

```
Firmware : Marlin 1.1.6

Machine : custom made

Board :  Ramps 1.4
```

configuration file : [Configuarion](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qeft8orIKeWt8YXmcQD-qB6OTy9slEKw)

Dual extruder setup: two nozzles with separate stepper motor for each nozzle. For the sake of simplicity let's say something like [this](https://www.robotdigg.com/product/243/MK7-Dual-Stepextruder)

Which category does this one go?? By reading marlin documentation it doesn't belong to any special category (???)

I only changed following in FW,

```
#define EXTRUDERS 2

#define TEMP_SENSOR_0 5
#define TEMP_SENSOR_1 5
```

I tested by sending T0 and T1 to select extruders and extruding them

Do I have to change anything else??

This is the test gcode:

```
G28       ;home

T0        ;select extruder 1
G0 X20    ;move to X 20
G92 E0    ;set current position of extruder as 0
G1 E10    ;extrude 10 mm
G92 E0    ;set current position of extruder as 0
G1 E-10   ;retract 10 mm

T1        ;select extruder 2
G92 E0    ;set current position of extruder as 0
G1 E5     ;extrude 5 mm
G4 P500   ;give a delay of 500 ms before next move

T0
G0 X 30
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500

T0
G0 X 40
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500

T0
G0 X 50
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500

T0
G0 X 60
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500

T0
G0 X70
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500

T0
G0 X70
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500

T0
G0 X80
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500
```

What it does is:

1. After homing, move to given position
2. Activate extruder 1 and extrude some(make impression)
3. then activating extruder 2 and extrude
4. move to next position and repeate

What I actually want is:

1. After homing, move to given position
2. Activate extruder 1 and extrude some (make impression)
3. then activating extruder 2
4. move extruder 2 to the position where extruder 1 extruded material
5. Extrude material (by extruder 2)
6. Move to next position and repeat

one way to achieve this is add an additional code after enabling extruder 2

eg:

```
T0
G0 X 20
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G0 X15   ; if X offset of E2 from E1 is 5mm, assuming no Y offset
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500

T0
G0 X 30
G92 E0
G1 E10
G92 E0
G1 E-10

T1
G0 X25
G92 E0
G1 E5
G4 P500
```

In plastic extrusion this is normally done by setting offset in Slic3r.

Is there any other way to do this, position E22 to the position of E1.
Is there any specific G/Mcode for it??
There's a provision to set offset in Marlin. But this is what it says in marlin documentation

**"Z hotend offset only available with DUAL_X_CARRIAGE or SWITCHING_NOZZLE."**

Does it work with normal dual extruders.?(Does mine come under any two system mentioned above?)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting project your are working on.

> Does it work with normal dual extruders.?(Does mine come under any two
>   system mentioned above?)

The hotend/extruder you mentioned above is a E3D Chimera like system. And it is not suited for your application because you cannot lower/lift the hotends independently from each other.

examples of these configurations

- DUAL_X_CARRIAGE:

  - look at BCN3D sigmax dual extruder
- SWITCHING_NOZZLE:

  - look at ultimaker 3 mechanism for lowering/switching the active hotend.

The above systems aren't well documentend and will be hard to make. 
I advice you to look into an interesting blog post from E3D about a tool changer. It is opensource, well documented so you're be able to create one yourself with tool heads for your application. A spade to create patterns in the powder. And a liquid tool to fill the patterns.

Comment: The extruder from robotdigg is there for the purpose of showing that I'm using two motor two nozzle system not one motor two nozzle one. I use a linear actuator like one from openbuilds as extruder 1 to make punctuation mark and and a Auger based pneumatic system to dispense liquid. Dispenser system is fixed but the linear actuator can move up and down